# Visual Basic . Net Questions x 2 (regarding If...then...else statement)

Tags: vb.net

two very silly questions below - they've just thrown me completely - please could you point me to which is correct and if you have time tell me why the others arent'.  Thanks - you have no idea how much this will help me.  I'm trying to teach myself VB and got this book of Amazon with questions but no answers and no where to find the answers.

**1. Which of the following is a valid If...then...else statement?**

a) pricelabel.text >0 andalso pricelabel.text<10

b) sales >500D orelse <800D

c) number >100 AndAlso number <=1000

d) state.ToUpper() = "Sydney" OrElse state.ToUpper = "Melbourne"

**2. Assume you want to compare the string contained in the text property of firstNameTextbox with John, which of the following conditions should you use in the If...then...else statement? (Be sure the condition with handle John, JOHN, john, etc).**

a) firstNameTextbox.text = toUpper ("JOHN")

b) firstNameTextbox.text.toUpper() = "John"

c) firstNameTextbox.text.toUpper() = "JOHN"

d) toUpper(firstname.text) = "JOHN"

Thanks so much – I'm trying to teach myself and just keep getting stuck. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It would be much more interesting (and better for your understanding) if you tried them out yourself by throwing a bit of code together instead of asking here. …

Comment: You should avoid this book! It's learning effect is small and why does it not at least provide the answers? Should you even buy a guide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1a: is wrong because you are comparing strings to integers.
1b: is wrong because you are not comparing 800D with anything.
1d: is wrong because you will never get a match because you are converting everthing to   upper case and comparing with a mixed case string.
1c: is the answer.

2a: will match upper case JOHN only.
2b: will never match since since you are converting the text to uppercase and comparing with a mixed case string.
2d: will match for uppercase JOHN only.
2c: since it converts the text to uppercase and compares with an uppercase string is the answer since it will match all combinations.

Comment: Why is 1d wrong? It's a valid(but senseless) statement regardless whether it will be evaluated to `true` or to `false`.

Comment: 1a) is valid if `Option Strict Off` – but that will hopefully not be the case, otherwise the book belongs right in the trash.

Comment: Yes it has the correct syntax but is logically flawed it will never evaluate to other than false. and since 1c has valid syntax and is actually able to evaluate to true or false. That is why I stated 1d as being wrong

Comment: I think 2a is wrong because ToUpper requires a string instance.  I don't think you can call it directly like that.

Comment: Thanks so much - I understand it now! I knew which ones were most likely to be right but the others threw me completely.  The book is Microsoft Visual Basic 2005:  Reloaded by Diane Zak and the publishers refuse to sell the 'solutions book' to anyone other than a lecturer.  I got it of Amazon and had no idea it didn't contain the solutions.  Your answers and discussion here has been invaluable.  Thanks so much.  You guys are absolute genius!